# R Shiny dataframe with new row addition (auto-population with levels for factor variables)

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I need to create editable dataframe which should allow addition/deletion/modification of records. Able to achieve addition/modification functionality with separate pop-up which would allow filling up form for new/existing record (change) [found [here]](http://enhancedatascience.com/2017/03/01/three-r-shiny-tricks-to-make-your-shiny-app-shines-33-buttons-to-delete-edit-and-compare-datatable-rows/). 
But instead, would like to have drop-down for each column, which would enable selection and subsequent saving of record (without popup).

Please let me know if any additional information needed.

Thanks for your help!

Thanks

Adding additional information:

Code as specified above is usable

[Existing DataFrame with Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hXK8.png)
[Pop-Up Form to select factor variable levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1BGG.png)

For new row additions/existing row changes; instead of pop-up form (to enter details for pre-defined factor variable levels), I want to enter details on new (blank row)/existing row itself.

[New Row with auto-population of levels for each variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zhq1.png)
Tihs should allow user for selection (as is possible in UI)

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What have you tried so far and what code are you specifically having trouble with?

Comment: You can check something like https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-crud-app/

Comment: @hdifen: I updated ticket with things I tried in "Additional information" section